# Remove frameborder in avada theme in youtube shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, themes, shortcode

i have using following shortcode.

```
[youtube id="" width="" height="" autoplay="" api_params="" class=""]
```

When i add this shortcode frameborder comes in iframe.

i need to remove `frameborder`

can anybody help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcode comes in fusion core plugin.

fusion-core/shortcodes.php

findout `add_shortcode('youtube', 'shortcode_youtube');`

remove frameborder from div under above shortcode.